# 100% bounce rate with non-zero average time in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, bounce-rate, session, bounce

[image]

Getting this on keyword reports: 100% bounce rate, 1 pageview and average session duration 24 minutes. I've gone through all of my other analytics properties and this is the first time I see this situation, in my opinion makes a bit of no sense.

Thinking about a couple of posibilities: - A user hits the site through that keyword, then exits, then comes back: session still valid but Analytics does not atribute the session to that particular keyword anymore. - Maybe a non-interaction event is set on the page affecting only the session duration (not sure this is a plausible scenario)

Anyone knows what's up?

Answer (score 2):

Non-interaction events would cause this behavior.  Senario:

1. User loads page
2. User reads the article for 24 minutes
3. Browser sends non-interactive event to Google Analytics
4. User closes the browser

In that case Google would know that the user stuck around for the 24 minutes, but because the non-interactive flag was set on the event, they would still be considered to bounce.

Comment: I have no events configured. Anyway a non-interaction event neither affects bounce rate nor time metrics. You can check it out from this post: http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2014/05/06/noninteraction-events-google-analytics/

Comment: You can find it also in the documentation https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide?hl=en
"opt_noninteraction (optional)
A boolean that when set to true, indicates that the event hit will not be used in bounce-rate calculation."